# Simple problem with alignment in Latex table

Tags: latex

I have a simple alignment question for Latex tables. At
the moment it looks as follows:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{| c | l | l | }
   \hline
    \tt {a} & $a = b + c + d + e + f + g + $ \\ 
        & $    e + f + g + h + i + j$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

The problem is, that the output looks as follows:

```
a = b + c + ...
e + f + ....
```

However, I would like to have it looks as

```
a = b + c + ...
    e + f + ...
```

Anyone an idea how I could do that in a table?

Thanks,
Klaus

Comment: Avoid tabular for set-off mathematics.  Using `$...$` is going to give you the wrong font size for the displayed maths.  Use align, as KennyTM says.

Answer (score 6):

Please use the `align` environment for multiline equations.

---

You can add a `\phantom{a = }` to indicate the should-be-existing spaces.

```
    & $\phantom{a = }e + f + g + h + i + j$ \\ \hline
```

Comment: Ah, the `\phantom` solution is nice too.

Comment: +1, right answer.  Cf. p7 of ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf, the amsmath style guide.  You will need \usepackage{amsmath}

Answer (score 2):

As KennyTM pointed out, you shouldn't typeset multiline equations using tables like this. But if you must do it, you could do it like this:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{| c | l @{} l | }
   \hline
    \tt {a} & $a =\;$ & $b + c + d + e + f + g + $ \\ 
        & & $e + f + g + h + i + j$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to make an additional column for the `a =` part; right-aligning it, and removing spacing with the next column for aesthetics:

```
\begin{tabular}{ c r @{} l } % you have one superfluous l
  \tt {a} & $a =$ & $b + c + d + e + f + g +$ \\ 
          &       & $e + f + g + h + i + j$ \\
\end{tabular}
```

Maybe you will need an explicit space after the `=` sign, so that it's properly spaced with the `b`.

Another solution would be to have a multiline equation in a single cell of the table, but that amounts to the same (you will need an `array` environment or something similar to wrap the left part).